# Android Google Place Picker working in Signed APK but not working in Live app

Tags: android, google-maps, key, google-places-api, developer-console

I have an application in which i have used Google Place Picker. There is very strange issue i am facing. When i am creating signed APK with my app's keystore, Place Picker is working very well. That same APK I have uploaded over Google PlayStore. When I come to open that Place Picker it automatically closed down.  I already read a lots of comments online and also here in SO. But I can not determine why its working well in signed APK and the same APK which is over Google PlayStore is not working.

When i checked logs of LIVE application of Google PlayStore it giving error like this :

```
Volley : [198] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403
for https: //www.googleapis.com/placesandroid/v1/search?key=MY_KEY/ ? V / ConnectivityManager : isActiveNetworkMetered() returns: true
/ ? E / AsyncOperation : serviceID = 65, operation = SearchPlaces
OperationException[Status {
 statusCode = PLACES_API_INVALID_APP, resolution = null
}]
```

I already have checked into my Google Developer Console that my key is same or not. I also check my SHA which I have created from my KeyStore file. And all are good (Otherwise it will also not works in Signed APK if anything wrongs there).

Here is how I calling Place Picker from my Activity

```
int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 999;
PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
startActivityForResult(builder.build(this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
```

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml file where i have give my API key in meta data which is into application tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example" >
    // ALL PERMISSIONS ARE HERE
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data            
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/MY_KEY" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

There is file which i deleted "release/values/google_maps_api.xml" which is automatic generated. As i already mentioned my API key into string.xml, So I deleted this whole values package from release package.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40975471/646806.. please check this

Comment: I have referred your given link. But can not understand why Google create an .xml file ane where ane when it create it? Also what i have to do to stop to create this new xml file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After several days of investing time for finding solution of this problem. Finally I got the solution. It is because of [Google Play App Signing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en)
.

> With Google Play App Signing: You sign your app with your upload key.
>   Then, Google verifies and removes the upload key signature. Finally,
>   Google re-signs the app with the original app signing key you provided
>   and delivers your app to the user.

So, when I Created API key for "Google Places API for Android" I have restricted that key using my package name and my SHA-1 of Signed APK's KeyStore.

Now that is under "Upload Certificate" and it is not used, as I have to pass my App Singing Certificate's SHA-1 to Google Developer Console. And after doing that my Google PlayStore's live app's Google PlacePicker working well. [image]

Comment: Genius! Its so bad that google makes these information so difficult to 'find and create developer's nightmare! Thank you so much!! @Ronak

Comment: That's why I answered my own question so other people don't spend more time on it. Thanks @Sjd

Comment: Believe it or not I came back here again to this thread to find your solution!! Thanks for posting this AWESOME answer man!!

Comment: @Sjd Glad that this post helps you again. Make +1 to post so others also gets benefits of this.

Comment: Still getting the problem even after adding the sign in key from the google playstore.

Comment: Hi @RonakJoshi, I've followed the directions but still getting the same issue. I keep getting a 403 error on my logs

Comment: Hi Very useful also because I have the same problem, just a question but the new SHA-1 key must replace the previous one in my API in Google Developer Console or should I add a new one? and if not, could you explain in detail where it needs to be changed? thank you so much!!

Comment: @Andrea You can replace the new key in Google Developer Console.