# Android Google Place picker working in debug and release APK but not in live app

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-places-api

PlacePicker work fine in debug and release apk but after uploading it in playstore the live app is no longer supporting placepicker. I followed all the steps stated in google's documentataion.I tried to use this  [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46307452/android-google-place-picker-working-in-signed-apk-but-not-working-in-live-app) as well but no success. Currently i have added the debug key, release key , sign in key and update key from  playstore into console.developers.com. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: same type of issued occurred due to release key. did you updated the file contains the release key?

Comment: Yes. Can you show me how you removed it.